# Method call expected in Android BaseAdapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to extend a `BaseAdapter` to make my custom `listview`. But it says:

> method call expected` in the getCount() method.

I know it's an Array, so how do I fetch it? I'm basically a nube in this field. Here is my code I have tried to apply:

```
public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
  private Context context;
  private String[] restaurant;
  private String[] address;
  private String[] time;
  private static LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
  public Resources res;
  int image[];
  ListModel tempvalues = null;
  int i=0;
  public customAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] rest, String[] add,String[] tim,int[] img){
    restaurant = rest;
    context=mainActivity;
    address= add;
    time = tim;
    image = img;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return restaurant.length(); // Method call expected.
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }
  public class Holder{
    TextView resname;
    TextView resadd;
    TextView restim;
    ImageView imageView;
  }
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowview;
    rowview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_for_restaurant_names,null);
    holder.resname = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.resnameTextView);
    holder.resadd = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.address_textview);
    holder.restim = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.time_textview);
    holder.imageView = (ImageView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    holder.resname.setText(restaurant[position]);
    holder.resadd.setText(address[position]);
    holder.restim.setText(time[position]);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(image[position]);
    rowview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return rowview;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  }
}
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: error cannot find symbol method length() - this is the error

Comment: let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
return restaurant.length();
```

to

```
return restaurant.length;
```

restaurant is a `Array` not a `List`

And one more thing I would like to suggest you,

Do not pass these arrays separately, because that will logically break the code, if some array size becomes less than the restaurant array.

I suggest you to use a model,

eg:

```
public class Event {

   private String restaurant;
   private String address;
   private String time;
   private int image;

   //getters and setters

}
```

and pass a list of `Event` s

like below,

```
     private List<Event> events;

        public customAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<Event>  events){

            this.events = events;
             layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }


    @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return events.size(); // Method call expected.
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int position) {
        return events.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
      }
```

and access that,

```
Event event = events.get(position);
 holder.resname.setText(event.getResturant());
    holder.resadd.setText(event.getAddress());
    holder.restim.setText(event.getTime());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(event.getImage());
```

And also,

You should not inflate the `ListView` Elements all the time you should reuse the already inflated elements.

```
       View view = convertView;
       if (view == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_for_restaurant_names,null);
        }
```

Comment: @Milind You should pass a List of Event objects into your adapter from your Adapter constructor. and set the adapter for the ListView, Got my point or no?